# how to check the value of a cookie in varnish

Tags: cookies, varnish

I have a cookie for language. I want to check if this cookie is set and to check its value to redirect the user to specific page.
the cookie name is **Lang** and its value might be **En,Fr,or Ar**

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "Lang"){
//now i want to check for the cookie value
//if LANG=="Ar"
// set req.url =  req.url "CookieValue"
}
```

anybody know how to check for cookie value in varnish??
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "Lang=En") {
   // do something with the English cookie
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "Lang=FR") {
   // do something with the French cookie
}
```